# What does "*ptrInt ++" do?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I'm implementing a template pointer wrapper similar in functionaltiy to `boost::shared_ptr`.

I have a pointer to an integer `ptrInt`.

What I want to do: **Increment the integer ptrInt points to.**

My initial code was this: `*ptrInt ++;`, although I also tried the same using `(*ptrInt) ++;`

Apparently, however, **this doesn't seem to do what I expected it to.**
In the end I got it working using `*ptrInt += 1;`, however I'm asking myself:

- What exactly does `*ptrInt ++;` do?
- Is there a more elegant solution to using `*ptrInt += 1;`?

Comment: <quote>I'm implementing a template pointer wrapper</quote> **STOP** don;t do it. Even the best C++ programmers get this wrong. Use the tools provided without re-inventing the wheel (there will be time for that later).

Answer (score 9):

```
*p++    // Return value of object that p points to and then increment the pointer
(*p)++  // As above, but increment the object afterwards, not the pointer
*p += 1 // Add one to the object p points to
```

The final two both increment the object, so I'm not sure why you didn't think it worked. If the expression is used as a value, the final form will return the value after being incremented but the others return the value before.

```
x = (*p)++; // original value in x

(*p)++;
x = *p;     // new value in X
```

or

```
x = ++*p;   // increment object and store new value in x
```

Comment: @Caleb: the first line works pretty much like @DigitalRoss describes. The pointer gets incremented and the result of the operation is *the old value* that then gets dereferenced.

Comment: @Martinho, serves me right for not trying it first. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

`*ptr++` equivalent to `*(ptr++)`

Answer (score 3):

`*ptrInt ++` will

1. increment ptrInt by 1
2. dereference old value of ptrInt

and `(*ptrInt) ++`  as well as `*ptrInt += 1` will do what you want.

See [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1):

(*ptr)++ should do it, unless you are using its value right away. Use ++*ptr then, which is equivalent to ++(*ptr) due to right-to-left associativity.

On a side note, [here is my smart pointer implementation](http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Type/Shared.hpp), perhaps it can help you in writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is evaluated using the rules for operator precedence.

The postfix version of `++` (the one where `++` comes after the variable) has a higher precedence than the `*` operator (indirection).

That is why `*ptr++` is equivalent to `*(ptr++)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `(*ptrInt)++`, which increments the object, which generally does the same as `*ptrInt += 1`. Maybe you have overloaded the `+=` operator, but not the `++` operators (postfix and prefix increment operators)?

Answer (score 0):

The *more* elegant way is whatever you tried before. i.e `(*ptrInt) ++;`

Since, you aren't satisfied with that, it might be because of the post - increment.

Say, `std::cout<<(*ptrInt) ++;` would have shown you the un-incremented value.

So, try giving `++(*ptrInt);` which might behave as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

`*ptrInt++` in your case does increment the pointer, nothing more (before that it fetches the value from the location at throws it away. of course if you use it in a more complex expression it will use it)

`(*ptrInt)++` does what you are looking for.